# How to make fork from dropbox php sdk and use in the my composer?

Tags: git, github, composer-php, fork, packagist

I did the fork from [dropbox php sdk](https://github.com/demisang/dropbox-sdk-php/tree/fix-64bit). I need to use it in the [my composer package](https://github.com/demisang/yii2-dropbox-backup/blob/master/composer.json), after I call `composer update` I get an error:

> Installation request for demi/dropbox-backup dev-master -> satisfiable by demi/dropbox-backup[dev-master].
>   demi/dropbox-backup dev-master requires dropbox/dropbox-sdk dev-v1.1.8 > no matching package found.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: what does this say: composer show dropbox/dropbox-sdk -v

Comment: ```source   : [git] https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-php.git 6901f8122458e0ce7e391468c0cf6cca465bd0ee```